# Java error 21 can not find symbol

Tags: java, location, find, symbols

I've been working on a code for a homework in which we have to create a code that ask for the number of people that are going to participate on an eating contest. The program is supposed to tell me first who is the one that ate the most and how much was it. I have my code almost done, basically I just have the part that will print the participant's name which ate the most. However, I am still struggling on the other part of my code, the error message that comes up is Java error 21 can not find symbol. I did checked that all of the brackets were there, that the code was inside the class and outside the main, but still I cant get it to work. This is how it looks so far

```
import java.io.*;


class TareaProgramaTelevisionV1{



    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.io.IOException{

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintStream out = System.out;

        String nombre;
        int numMayor;
        int k;

        out.println("Digite el numero de participantes (-1 para finalizar) ");
        k=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());


        numMayor = ganadorDelConcurso(comida1, comida2, comida3);
        out.println(numMayor);

        while(k!=-1){

        out.print("Digite el nombre del participante");
        nombre = in.readLine();
        for (int contComida=0; contComida<3; contComida++){


        int comida1;
        int comida2;
        int comida3;

        out.println("Cuanto consumió en el primer bocado?");
        comida1=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        out.println("Cuanto consumió en el segundo bocado?");
        comida2=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        out.println("Cuanto consumió en el tercer bocado?");
        comida3=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());


                    }

                }   

            }
        static int ganadorDelConcurso(int pcomida1, int pcomida2, int pcomida3){

            int numMayor=0;
            int comidaTragada;

            comidaTragada= pcomida1 + pcomida2 + pcomida3;

        if (comidaTragada>numMayor){

            numMayor= numMayor + comidaTragada;
            return numMayor;
        }
    } 
}
```

The variables are in spanish because this is how is supposed to print out the information. The variable numMayor is the one which will return how much did the person ate in total, pcomida1,2 and 3 are how much is the person eating in 3 attempts and finally I used firstly a while so that I can do it for as many people as it is needed as long as the user doesn't enter -1. Any help with this is really apprecciate it.

Comment: in your function `ganadorDelConcurso()` I don't see a return if `comidaTragada<= numMayor` ? Also, pls post the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: Should I create another routine for the "if(comidaTragada...."? The thing is that I thought that I could do the "if" evaluation and then ask for the return right away.

Comment: This is the error I was getting. I couldnt copied it all so I will split it in two
C:\Users\Carlos\Documents\Ejemplos Programacion\Diagramas de Flujo y Java\TareaProgramaTelevisionV1.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        numMayor = ganadorDelConcurso(comida1, comida2, comida3);
                                      ^
  
  symbol:   variable comida3
  location: class TareaProgramaTelevisionV1
3 errors

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that there is a missing symbol on line 21.  Which is the reference to `comida1` (and the other variables on that line).  You can't reference a variable before it is declared (which you are doing in the while/for loops on lines 31 to 33.  You either need to move the variable declarations up, or declare and use different variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I did have the variable's declarations up first but I was getting another error as well

Comment: It is related to the return statement that Bimalesh Jha just said. I will correct that part and see if I can get it working now, thanks for your help